# Query with CONTAINS on a number cast to a string in stored procedure does not work

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I try to write a stored procedure in cosmos db to execute a query which return some objects depending on 2 properties : a string and an int. Parameters taken by the procedure have to be string but the second property is an int in the document.

The query works well when it's executed outside the procedure but when it is in the procedure it return an empty array every time.

I tried to create the procedure with a simple query like : 
`'SELECT * FROM listeLignes l'`, but it also returns an empty array every time.

Actually, even the generated stored procedure example does not work and return an empty result.

There is not a lots of objects in the collection.

```
function LigneVoiesByCodeLigneOrText(libelle, codeLigne) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var query = 'SELECT * FROM l WHERE 1=1 ';

    if(libelle != null){
        query = query + 'AND CONTAINS(l.libelle, "'+ libelle +'") ';
    }

    if(codeLigne != null){
       query = query + 'AND CONTAINS(toString(l.codeLigne), "'+ codeLigne +'") ';
    }

    console.log(query);

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        query,
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (!feed || !feed.length) {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                response.setBody('no docs found');
            } else {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                var body = { feed : feed[0] };
                response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
            }
        });

        if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Since `There is not a lots of objects in the collection` you said, you could do the trick in your sql with [udf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#udfs) in cosmos db.

***udf:***

[image]

***stored procedure:***(notice `CONTAINS(udf.bbb(l.countyid)` please)

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample(libelle,codeLigne) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var query = 'SELECT l.id,l.countyid FROM l WHERE 1=1 ';

    if(libelle != null){
        query = query + 'AND CONTAINS(l.id, "'+ libelle +'") ';
    }

    if(codeLigne != null){
       query = query + 'AND CONTAINS(udf.bbb(l.countyid), "'+ codeLigne +'") ';
    }

    console.log(query);

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        query,
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody(feed);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Comment: The toString() function I am using is already like your udf.bbb() function. I think  that the problem come from the execution of a stored procedure in the "Cosmos DB editor" because even the sample stored proc does not work and when I execute the query generated  : SELECT * FROM l WHERE 1=1 AND CONTAINS(l.libelle, \"string\") AND CONTAINS(toString(l.codeLigne),\"number\"),it does work. 
I will try to execute the stored procedure from a c# / .net project and see if it works.